# Hyperlink to a single line of text field using sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I am using Sharepoint 2010 and I have created a single line of text field column in document library. I would like to hyperlink the text in that column to a file uploaded into document library.If I use the below code in sharepoint designer its not working.Can someone please help me with this.

```
<a href="/{$thisNode/@FileLeafRef}"><xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></a>
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
The strange thing is, if i expose the name column in the view then everything is working fine. I have no clue why its behaving like this. Can someone please explian me.